# Windows 10 Taskbar size seems too large

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, gui, windows-10-v1703

I am using Windows 10 with the Creators Update (version 1703). Since horizontal screen real estate is scarce these days, I wanted to try moving the taskbar to either side of my screen. This makes the taskbar unnecessarily large to my taste, even though I use the "small icon" setting. It does not help to turn off the clock, as that is the largest icon/item. I think the taskbar could be half as small, but it won't let me resize it with the taskbar unlocked, I can only make it larger.

See this screenshot:

[image: Large taskbar icons]

Comment: Place the cursor near the edge of the taskbar and it changes to a double-headed arrow. Then drag inside to shrink the size of it.

Comment: @Biswa that won't make it smaller than in the image. Please try something like this first before suggesting it to others. There's a hidden setting that prevents from making the taskbar smaller, but software such as Windows 7 Taskbar tweaker+ can make it smaller.

Comment: change display setting to make date smaller by dispalying 27-5-17, maybe this makes it smaller.